# What is the interaction between Chilling Tentacles and Repelling Blast?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock

Using my invisibility, I want to do the following:

1. Set up Chilling Tentacles *behind* my enemies.
2. Fire a Repelling Cone at my enemies to knock them through the Chilling Tentacles zone.

I want to do it in this order because activating chilling tentacles behind them instead of on them will allow my invisibility to stay in-tact. Once they are hit with the repelling blast into the tentacles, their fate is sealed.

When they fly through the chilling tentacles' threat area, I have some questions, though:

1. Are the tentacles able to grasp the "flying" characters as they are knocked through the threat zone?  The tentacles don't use attacks of opportunity (which the blast does not provide), they simply grasp anything that enters the area.
2. If they do successfully grab them, does that halting of momentum add damage from repelling blast's secondary effect (1d6/10' traveled)?

Comment: "does that halting of momentum " - are you sure you want to mix actual physics with game mechanics? You know, this does not end well most of the time.

Comment: This is not actual physics - that is from the falling rule, which has been (iirc) adjudicated to also apply to vertical and horizontal travel which results in a sudden stop; as in *Reverse Gravity*, among others. Note that if they travel 9' (in any direction) and suddenly stop, there is no damage - which further proves that it is not real physics involved. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Chilling Tentacles invocation says "Any creature that enters the area of the spell is immediately attacked by the tentacles", and if the attack succeeds the grapple will prevent further movement.  If the attack fails, a Rules As Written interpretation would say that the creature keeps moving.  Your DM might issue a house rule saying that the tentacles slow the creature's flight even if it fights off the grapple.
2. The Repelling Blast invocation says the creature takes damage if it "strikes a wall", and a tentacle is not a wall.  Your DM might issue a house rule, but Rules As Written the creature does not take damage if stopped in this way.

Also, I don't think your plan will work with respect to invisibility.  I'm pretty sure that using a repelling cone on a creature will break your invisibility effect.

Comment: The repelling cone will reveal me, but the goal is to cast tentacles first, then knock them into the tentacles with the repelling blast so that I won't be revealed until they are flying through the air.

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe to being affected, No to the damage as described.

**Area of Effect:**
If the path of travel takes them through the area of effect, then they will be brought to a halt within the area and affected by the effect, if, and only if:

- the effect has an AoO or Immediate action type effect,
- it specifically affects all targets automatically upon entry, travel through, or exit from the area of effect,
- OR if the end of distance traveled is within the area of effect.

---

**Damage:**
However, the damage is more of an issue. Does a tentacle grabbing counts as a sudden enough halt? Or does it simply grab, and bend with the force of travel, bringing the grabbed entity to a halt more slowly?

D&D is silent regarding real physics, and D&D magic behaves in ways which do not make sense. You could just as well ask if a character could throw themselves off a cliff and cast that spell so as to avoid the falling damage at the bottom.

**Possible resolution:**
You also have the approach of order of operations. Since the cone takes first effect, and the effect in question does not have an AoO or interrupt effect (such as an immediate action), then I would personally rule to resolve the cone's effects first, falling damage (if any, and as per the falling rules, errata and FAQ) second, and then **IF** they end up in the effect's area after all of that, the effect in question third.

I would also (as a player) attempt to carefully place the area of effect to coincide with the expected travel distance.